# JSHint not working with Vim

Tags: vim, jshint, pathogen

Using Ubuntu 12.

I installed jshint with

```
sudo npm install jshint -g

which jshint
```

shows 
    /usr/local/bin/jshint, which is also in the PATH variable

Then, I downloaded https://github.com/walm/jshint.vim/blob/master/plugin/jshint.vim
and put it in ~/.vim/bundle/jshint.vim (I am using Pathogen)

Now, when opening a js-File, such as

```
vim test.js
```

errors are not detected.

```
:JSHint
```

results in "Not an editor command: JSHint"

```
:Helptags
```

results in, well, nothing.. I don't really see what that command is for, anyway..

I am a vim noob, but other pathogen bundles seem to work, so I do not really know what is not working here..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default way to install plugins is to put their individual pieces in some subdirectories of your `~/.vim/` directory. Taking this plugin as example:

```
~/.vim/plugin/jshint.vim
~/.vim/doc/jshint.txt
```

The `:Helptags` command is used to generate the index (`tags`) used by Vim to navigate through the documentation of third party plugins. You are supposed to use it like that:

```
:Helptags ~/.vim/doc
```

The idea behind Pathogen and other plugin managers is that each plugin should be in its own directory rather than be scattered through your `~/.vim/` directory. In Pathogen's case (and others followed, but there's no standard), that's the bundle directory: `~/.vim/bundle/`.

Therefore, the correct location for your plugin should be:

```
~/.vim/bundle/jshint/plugin/jshint.vim
~/.vim/bundle/jshint/doc/jshint.txt
~/.vim/bundle/jshint/README.md
~/.vim/bundle/jshint/LICENSE
```

In order for pathogen to work its magic, you are supposed to add these two lines to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
silent! call pathogen#infect()
silent! call pathogen#helptags()
```

The first line takes care of "registering" and loading each plugin found in `~/.vim/bundle/`. The second line indexes their documentation, the equivalent of `:Helptags …` that you don't need to run, then.

So…

1. Make sure Pathogen is installed and configured correctly.
2. Install the JSHint plugin where it should be.
3. ?
4. Enjoy writing JavaScript in Vim!

---

To run `:JSHint` on the current buffer every time you write it, add this line to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd! BufWritePost *.js JSHint
```

Comment: Great, it works. Thanks for your exhaustive answer. Still, I have 1-2 questions. How can I enable JSHint so that everytime I write to a file, (:w), JSHint is executes? Right now it only works when I manually call :JSHint. Secondly, the first error/notice I get in JSHint is the Bad option: 'ender', and I suppose it has something to do with its configuration.. do you know anything about that?

Comment: I have no experience with JSHint, you'll have to follow the manual to configure it properly. I'll edit my answer for the `:w`.

Comment: Check the options you are using to configure jshint. For example, look in ~/.jshintrc and search for the option "ender". If it's there remove it, and it should fix the problem.